# How to obtain a value of an input (type text) on server side in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html

Using the HTML markup

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
  <input id="donkey" type="text" placeholder="monkey" runat="server" />
</form>
```

I hoped to get the entered value in code behind by

```
String s = Request.Form["donkey"];
```

but it only produces null value. When I investigate the data structure I get something like `$ctl00$main$donkey` so I know it's there. After a while, I simply switched to

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox id="donkey" type="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

but I still wonder how to reference the object from server-side if I for some reason won't switch to ASP-component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to get value of input use like this

```
  String s = donkey.value;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to access to the value using request.form, add name attribute to input tag and remove runat attribute.

```
<input id="donkey" name="donkey" type="text" />
```

Otherwise use

```
<asp:TextBox ID="donkey" type="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and on cs

```
string s = donkey.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually much smoother to use the direct approach of Yograj and User11 but i'll keep the name-attribute in mind. I prefer to use as few as possible in order not to clutter the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just `donkey.Value` will return the value from text input which should have `runat="server"`. It will create an object of `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about ASP.net but for a regular form field to submit properly it should have a `name` attribute.  That would be the key that you could then lookup the form value.